# GraphQL Dynamic Query with where clause

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, hasura

I am trying to query jobs based on three variable parameters.

1. Location
2. Category
3. Type

Below is my Query:

```
query getJobsSearch($location: String, $type: String, $category: String) {
  jobs(order_by: {created_at: desc}, where: {deleted_at: {_is_null: true}, created_at: {_gt: "2021-06-16T10:06:38.551984+00:00"}, job_category: {slug: {_eq: $category}}, location: {slug: {_eq: $location}}, job_type: {slug: {_eq: $type}}}, limit: 50) {
    jobId
    title
    company_name
    job_category {
      name
      slug
    }
    job_type {
      name
      slug
    }
    isRemote
    location {
      city
      slug
    }
    created_at
  }
}
```

Passing the variables as follows:

```
{"location":  "new-delhi", "type": "full-time", "category": "finance"}
```

To be able to now call all the jobs with no filters I am passing empty strings in the variable as follows

```
{"location":  "", "type": "", "category": ""}
```

When I pass the above I am getting `zero` results back but my tables have data in them.

Also when I need to query just based on location I am trying to pass the following variables with `type` and `category` as empty strings:

```
{"location":  "new-delhi", "type": "", "category": ""}
```

How can we reset the variables so that I get back all the listing without being filtered based on `location, category or type`?

Is it the right way to pass `""` when you do not want to apply the where clause for a query.

In Ruby we are so used to chaining the query this feels weird and complex. Hope to get some help.

Comment: preapre and pass entire `where` object - no graphql syntax for conditionals

Comment: @xadm can you please point me to an example. Am confused. this is first time. I am trying to google but not able to figure what exactly to search.

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations ... read your `$where` type from API docs/specs (playground)

Comment: @xadm let me do that and get back if I have any queries. thanks a lot.